# phonegap ajax call getting error '$ is not defined'

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I am making an AJAX request in my Phonegap application. The code is:

```
function remoteCall()
{
  alert("Remote call func called");

  try
  {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://192.168.1.200/testing/testConn.php',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data)
       {
          if(data == '')
              alert("No data received from server");
          else
          alert("Data received from server = "+data.postcode);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
       {
           console.log(textStatus);
           alert('FAIL !!!');
       },

     });
  }//end of try().
  catch(e)
  {
        alert("error = "+e.message);
  }

}//END OF FUNC remoteCall.
```

I have also added the following line in `<head>` to avoid the jQuery conflict.

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

My server side file is:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

$retArray = array();
$retArray['postcode']= 'm14';
$retArray['brand']= '1';
$retArray['product_type']= '1';

$jsondata =  json_encode($retArray);

return $jsondata;
?>
```

I am getting first alert message but later I am getting the error, "$ is not undefined". I have no idea how to fix this; can anyone help?

I am able to overcome that error of "$ is undefined", now i am not getting any errors and also I am not getting any output...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/  Setting that means you can't use $ but should use jQuery in it's place

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you add jquery files before adding the js file containing your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script> in <head>, do i need to any other jquery files?

Comment: ok so you have added your js file reference after the reference you mentioned in comment. right?

Comment: well the last thing then what i can guess is, make sure that you have added all the jQuery references of the same version.

Comment: @user2186239 It looks like you've imported jQuery mobile,  I think you'll also have to import the base jQuery library as well.

Answer (score 1):

`<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>` means that you must refer to the jQuery object as `jQuery` and not `$`. Change your references from `$` to `jQuery` and it should work.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I changed $ to jQuery now i am getting "jQuery is not defined". I tried after remove that <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script> and replace jQuery with $ still I am getting that "$ is undefined" error. any idea.....

Comment: You probably haven't imported the jQuery library. You should have something like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` somewhere in your html.

Comment: @user2186239 Note that you'll have to import the jQuery library BEFORE your javascript

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem... :)

Following lines solved my $ and jQuery problem

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Thanks to Ali and cfs :) )

And in server file i changed return to echo

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

$retArray = array();
$retArray["postcode"]= "m14";
$retArray["brand"]= "1";
$retArray["product_type"]= "1";

$jsondata =  json_encode($retArray);
echo $jsondata;

?>
```

Now I am able to get the server details.

Thanks to all for the replies.... :)